# Counting number of rows in Attribute Table using expression?

Tags: arcmap

I am trying to figure out how to streamline a formula I am using in ArcMap.

I am using the `"select by attributes"` tool in ArcMap to select rows based on the total number of rows in the target attribute table. Right now I am using a formula that requires that I look at the number of rows in the table, and then replace the words "number of records in table" with the actual number. Since I do this quite a few times every day, I am looking for a way to avoid having to look at the attribute table and type in the number of rows in my formula.

Here is the formula I am using. How could this be modified to count the number of rows?

```
MOD(OBJECTID+(2*(number of records in table/20))-0,(number of records in table/20))=0
```

Comment: Which format is your data stored in? Is it shapefile, personal/file geodatabase, SQL Server... ? You could try writing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTableName` directly in the Select By Attributes expression to get the number of records, however, this may not work depending on your data format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I will be using this inside of a Personal Geodatabase.
I tried using SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTableName in the expression, however it does not seem to work.

Comment: MOD has to be used as an operator in Access, not a function, so I think you will have to try it this way: `(OBJECTID+(SELECT COUNT(*)/10 FROM YourTableName)) MOD (SELECT COUNT(*)/20 FROM YourTableName)=0` Also don't forget to change both 'YourTableName' with your actual table name.

Answer (score 1):

If using ArcPy is an option you can create a function then call the function every time you want to select:

```py
def selectThem(feature_layer):
    import arcpy
    rowcount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(in_rows=fc).getOutput(0))
    oidfield = arcpy.Describe(fc).OIDFieldName
    sql = "MOD({0}+(2*({1}/20))-0,({1}/10))=0".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc,oidfield), rowcount)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=fc, 
                                            where_clause=sql)
```

[image: example]